# Absolute convergence in Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Show that, if $\sum_{n\ge 1}x_{n}$ is absolutely convergent then $\sum_{n\ge 1}x_{n}$ is convergent and 
$$\left\|\sum_{n\ge 1}x_{n}\right\|\le \sum_{n\ge 1}\|x_{n}\|$$

I have tried this :
Let $\sum_{n\ge1}x_{n}$ be absolutely convergent, this is $\sum_{n\ge1}
   \|x_{n}\|$ converges. So put $s_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{n}$ and 
      $p_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\|x_{n}\|$. We want to proof that $s_{n}$ is a 
      Cauchy sequence, and as $X$ is a Banach space it will follow  that 
      $s_{n}$ is convergent.
      But this is straight forward, because as $p_{n}$ is convergent we know that 
      $$\sum_{n\ge k}\|x_{n}\|\rightarrow 0\mbox{ when } k\rightarrow\infty, $$
      or more precisely given any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ 
      such that 
      $$\sum_{n\ge k}\|x_{n}\|<\varepsilon,~\forall n\ge N$$ and so
      $$\|s_{n}-s_{m}\|=\left\|\sum_{k=\min\{m,n\}}^{\max\{m,n\}}x_{k}\right\|
   \le \sum_{k\ge\min\{m,n\}}\|x_{k}\|<\varepsilon, \forall ~m,n\ge N.$$
      This proves that $s_{n}$ is convergent because any Banach space is complete. As for any integer $k$ 
      $$\left\| \sum_{n=1}^{k}x_{n}\right\|\le \sum_{n=1}^{k}\|x_{n}\|$$
      and the norm $\|\cdot\|$ is continuous, as $k\rightarrow\infty$ we get 
      $$\left\|\sum_{n\ge 1}x_{n}\right\|\le \sum_{n\ge 1}\|x_{n}\|.$$
Can anyone say if my solution is correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @EDUARDO Can you please correct the spelling from $Benach$ space to $Banach$ space ?

Comment: Sure, Thank you @seeker !