# If the absolute value of an infinite series is bounded above, then the infinite series absolutely converges?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, inner-products, absolute-convergence

I am attempting to follow this simple example found in Further Linear Algebra by Blyth & Robertson page 14. It deduces that a sequence of partial sums must be absolutely convergent when bounded above. But I don't believe that the partial sums are necessarily monotonically increasing (there could be negative summands within each partial sum). I'm missing something obvious.

[screenshot from book example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jpo7.jpg)

In case the image does not appear, here is the context:
The book is using Cauchy Schwarz to show that the standard inner product is well-defined (convergent) in the space of square summable real sequences.

Let $a = (a_1, a_2, ... )$ and $b = (b_1, b_2, ...)$ be such that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |a_i|^2$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} |b_i|^2$ converge.

Define the following sequences of partial sums:

$p_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i b_i$ and $q_n = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} |a_i|^2 \sum_{i=1}^{n} |b_i|^2  }$ for $n=1, 2, ...$

$(q_n)$ converges because $a$ and $b$ are square summable.
By Cauchy Schwarz, $|p_n| \leq q_n$. The book then deduces that $(p_n)$ is therefore an absolutely convergent sequence. I don't see how this could be applying the bounded monotone convergence theorem because the sum $p_n$ could contain negative summands, making the sequence $(|p_1|, |p_2|, ...)$ not necessarily monotonic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is certainly not true that an upper bound on the absolute value of partial sums implies convergence of a series (consider $1-1+1-1\dots$).

Therefore, I think from context we can infer that what the author intended (or should have intended) to argue was as follows:

Define $r_n=\sum_{i=1}^n |a_ib_i|$, and show that $r_n\leq q_n$.  This follows from Cauchy Schwarz just as it did for $|p_n|$.

Therefore, since $r_n$ (which ***is*** monotone, and bounded by $\lim_{n\to\infty} q_n$) converges, $p_n$
converges as well, by the result that [absolute convergence of a series implies convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2180369/absolute-convergence-implies-convergence-in-complete-spaces) (applied here to $\mathbb R$).

Comment: I don't understand how $r_n \leq q_n $ follows from Cauchy Schwarz. $r_n$ is larger than $|p_n|$ by triangle inequality

Comment: We don't compare with $p_n$, we just use Cauchy Schwartz with $a_n$ and $b_n$ replaced with $|a_n|$ and $|b_n|$.